# How to Detect if Cookies Are Disabled on Microsoft Edge / Windows 10?

Tags: javascript, cookies, microsoft-edge

I have some code that works in every other browser, but not in Windows 10 / Microsoft Edge. Any ideas?

```js
function areCookiesEnabled() {
  // Quick test if browser has cookieEnabled host property
  if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    return true;
  }
  // Create cookie
  document.cookie = "cookietest=1";
  var ret = document.cookie.indexOf("cookietest=") !== -1;
  // Delete cookie
  document.cookie = "cookietest=1; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";
  return ret;
}

if (areCookiesEnabled()) {
  alert("Cookies are enabled!");
} else {
  alert("Cookies are not enabled!");
}
```

*Cookies are blocked in settings*

[image: Cookies are blocked in settings]

*Stack Overflow says that cookies are enabled*

[image: Stack Overflow says that cookies are enabled]

Comment: I tried it over Microsoft Edge on Win10 Virtual Machine (http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/) with a very simple html test page and it works fine. Can you please share your whole markup?

Comment: @Roman I added some more details in the description. Also I think I titled my question wrong. I can't detect that cookies are *disabled*. Does that really work for you when you use the Win10 VM? Thanks so much for checking this out.

Comment: No I can confirm that Edge is not consistent at all. I have cookies blocked, but it still lets me drop a cookie. This is not the case on any other browser. It's mind blowing that with cookies disabled, you're still able to drop a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a cookie and then test it i have small but very usefull library for that [here](https://github.com/NikosEfthias/cookier) by this you can do something like this

```
if(navigator.cookieEnabled||cookier.make("test","test",1))
//if one of these returns true {
    if(cookier.parse("test))
    //if test cookie is set
    {
        console.log("cookies are allowed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a Cookie library that tests it the proper way, by actually creating a real cookie:

https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies

The method used is `Cookies.enabled`. Here's the section of code that the author used:

```
 var testKey = 'cookies.js';
 var areEnabled = Cookies.set(testKey, 1).get(testKey) === '1';
 Cookies.expire(testKey);
 return areEnabled;
```

I tried this inside the Win10/Edge dev tools and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include separate js then, you can update your function as below

```
function areCookiesEnabled() {
var cookieEnabled = navigator.cookieEnabled;

// When cookieEnabled flag is present and false then cookies are disabled.
if (cookieEnabled === false) {
    return false;
}

var isIE =  /*@cc_on!@*/false;
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

// try to set a test cookie if we can't see any cookies and we're using 
// either a browser that doesn't support navigator.cookieEnabled
// or IE / Edge (which always returns true for navigator.cookieEnabled)
if ((cookieEnabled === null || isIE || isEdge)) {
    document.cookie = "testcookie=1";

    if (GetCookieValue("testcookie") != "1") {
        return false;
    } else {
        document.cookie = "testcookie=; expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString();
    }
}

return true;
}

// Get cookie value by passing the key.
function GetCookieValue(strKey) {

// split cookies by '; ', keep space as it is.
var arrCookies = document.cookie.split('; ');

for (var i = 0; i < arrCookies.length; i++) {

    var keyValuePair = GetKeyValuePair(arrCookies[i]);

    // Match the key.
    if (keyValuePair.key === strKey) {
        // return value of matched key.
        return keyValuePair.value;
    }
}

// Return an empty string if key is not present.
return "";
}

// Get key value pair from the cookie string.
function GetKeyValuePair(strCookie) {

// "=" is a valid character in a cookie value according to RFC6265, so cannot `split('=')`
var separatorIndex = strCookie.indexOf('=');

// IE omits the "=" when the cookie value is an empty string
separatorIndex = separatorIndex < 0 ? strCookie.length : separatorIndex;

var key = strCookie.substr(0, separatorIndex);
var decodedKey;

try {
    decodedKey = decodeURIComponent(key);
} catch (e) {
}

return {
    key: decodedKey,
    value: strCookie.substr(separatorIndex + 1)
};
};
```

I had fixed this problem this way.